# How sustainable is using a template for Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I am thinking about using a template in Google Docs (flow chart, context diagram).
Now these templates are designed by private persons and I am asking how sustainable are these templates. I mean if I obtain one, will there be a risk, that after a year the template will not work anymore, because Google has changed something or thee user deleted the template ?

how sustainable is using a template for Google Docs ?

Answer (score 3):

If I used a template designed by someone else, the first thing I would do is make my own copy of the template   (File > save a copy), and all my work would start from that.

There is always a risk with Google products that something will stop working.   Especially so when clever people use scripting or otherwise bend the functionality beyond what was expected.    But if only standard features are used, this is likely to be less of an issue.

Comment: It's useful to copy the template in case you want to create more docs from it in the future, but presumably every doc created from a template no longer depends on that template. Or is that wrong?